# How do I get the AstNode from some Element, in Dart Analyzer / source-gen?

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I'm using `source_gen` to parse some Dart files, through the Dart `analyzer`.

I'm extending `GeneratorForAnnotation<>`, and overriding method 
`FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep)`.
This method gives me a base element, which I navigate until I find some other element, say a `MethodElement`.

Once I get hold of this `MethodElement`, I want to analyze 
the method's block, in detail. I'd like something like this:

```
AstNode node = methodElement.computeNode();
```

In more detail:

```
class MyGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<MyAnnotation> {

    @override
    FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
        Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep,
    ) {
      if (element is ClassElement)
        for (MethodElement methodElement in element.methods) {
          AstNode node = methodElement.computeNode();
          processMyNode(node);
        }
      else
        throw AssertionError();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `computeNode` is deprecated. If I try to call it, I get:

```
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'RestrictedAnalysisContext' has no instance method 'resolveCompilationUnit' with matching arguments.
Receiver: Instance of 'RestrictedAnalysisContext'
Tried calling: resolveCompilationUnit(Instance of 'FileSource', Instance of 'LibraryElementImpl')
Found: resolveCompilationUnit(Source, LibraryElement) => CompilationUnit
```

My question: How can I get the `AstNode`?

Answer (score 12):

Got it:

```
AstNode getAstNodeFromElement(Element element) {
  AnalysisSession session = element.session;
  ParsedLibraryResult parsedLibResult = session.getParsedLibraryByElement(element.library);
  ElementDeclarationResult elDeclarationResult = parsedLibResult.getElementDeclaration(element);
  return elDeclarationResult.node;
}
```

Comment: You can also use [`NodeLocator`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/b8c5ecd5aaecf0a70794d344bfdf5a3064e3bb12/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/dart/ast/utilities.dart#L2444)
 or [`NodeLocator2`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/b8c5ecd5aaecf0a70794d344bfdf5a3064e3bb12/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/dart/ast/utilities.dart#L2537), from the `analyzer` package.
For some reason it's not exported to the API documentation, but it's very useful. There's also a counterpart called `ElementLocator` that does the opposite: get an `Element` from an `AstNode`.

Answer (score 2):

While MarcG's solution works for most elements, it does not work for the root `LibraryElement`s themselves.

To get the `AstNode` (or, more specifically, a `CompilationUnit`) for a `LibraryElement`'s defining `CompilationUnitElement`, the following can be done:

```dart
final libraryCompilationUnit = (libraryElement.session
        .getParsedLibraryByElement(libraryElement) as ParsedLibraryResult)
    .units[0]
    .unit;
```