# Find function/method body explicit dependency types using Dart analyzer package

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I would like to understand how can I analyze methods / functions body to find types that are explicitly referenced from it. I have success analyzing method declaration (return type, parameter types, etc..), however I have no idea how to do that for body.

Assuming following function:

```dart
String someFunction(int param) {
  final list = <String>['a', 'b', 'c'];                     // -> DartTypes: String, List<String>
  final myClass = MyClass<Arg>();                           // -> DartTypes: Arg, MyClass<Arg>
  final functionCall = anotherFunction<FunctionArg<Arg>>(); // -> DartTypes: Arg, FunctionArg<Arg>
  return 'result';
}

// At is point I would like to know that my function depends on
// String, List<String>, Arg, MyClass<Arg>, FunctionArg<Arg>
// in term of DartType instances with proper typeArguments.
```

I tried getting AstNode for method element described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57043177/2033394

However I could not get elements from nodes to figure out their types. Their `declaredElement` values are always null. So I can not get back to Element API from AST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've used the exact snippet from the answer you've referenced, the problem is likely in `getParsedLibraryByElement()`. This method only parses the referenced library - meaning that you'll get an AST that doesn't necessarily have semantic references (like the `declaredElement` of AST nodes) set.

Instead, you'll want to use [`getResolvedLibraryByElement`](https://pub.dev/documentation/analyzer/latest/dart_analysis_session/AnalysisSession/getResolvedLibraryByElement.html). The AST returned by that method will have its types and references fully resolved.

With the resolved AST, you could visit the body of the method with a custom visitor to find type references. Your definition of "referenced types" isn't really exact - but perhaps you can collect types in `visitNamedType` for type references and `visitVariableDeclaration` to collect the types of variables.

Comment: Many thanks, @simolus3. Works as a charm!